# jquery how to hide a single element from others if not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, show-hide

I am working on a sidebar with (single menu) and (submenus).

The menus that contains (submenu) has (+-) toggle, and the ones with singles has nothing.

How can I hide the (+-) of the single menus from other similar elements.

I have tried this way, it hides for all of them.

**HTML**

```
<div class="multitoggle">
    <ul id="accordions">
        <li class="nav-parents">
            <div class="link"> <span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span> <a href="#">CURRENT ACCOUNTS</a></div>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="../current/third-level.php">MPOWER CLASSIC</a></li>
                <li><a href="../current/third-level.php">MPOWER GOLD</a></li>
                <li><a href="../current/third-level.php">MPOWER PLATINUM</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-parents">
            <div class="link"> <span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span> <a href="#">OUR SEGMENTS</a></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(window ).load(function(e) {
    if ($('.nav-parents').has('submenu').length == 0) {
        $('.nav-parents').find('.plus, .minus').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Comment: why don't you just delete the spans elements from the menus that don't have sub menus?

Comment: It is being integrated into Kentico cms, and the CMS sees all sidebars as the same on default. So it adds the (+-) by default.

That's why I need to write a custom script for that

Comment: @SowemimoBamidele your code actually worked, you just forgot `.` in the submenu, because you were looking for a class and not element, Azim's is one line, but harder to read.

Comment: No. Only dot will not make it work. @YanMayatskiy

Comment: @Azim you are right, was pretty sure he was doing a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually only `has()` will not work in this case. You have to use the combination of `not()` and `has()`. And also you missed the dot before `submenu`. You can do it like following.

```
$(window ).load(function(e) {
    $('.nav-parents').not(':has(.submenu)').find('.plus, .minus').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement doesn't do much here, because when you run this:

```
$('.nav-parents').find('.plus, .minus').css('display', 'none');
```

it will just select all `.nav-parents` again and hide their pluses and minuses.

To select only the nav-parents with no submenu, you should use this jQuery code:

```
$('.nav-parents').not(':has(.submenu)')
```

Here is your code working in a snippet:

```js
$(window).load(function(e) {
    $('.nav-parents')
      .not(':has(.submenu)')
      .find('.plus, .minus')
      .hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multitoggle">
  <ul id="accordions">
    <li class="nav-parents">
      <div class="link">
        <span class="plus">+</span>
        <span class="minus">-</span>
        <a href="#">CURRENT ACCOUNTS</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>
          <a href="../current/third-level.php">MPOWER CLASSIC</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="../current/third-level.php">MPOWER GOLD</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="../current/third-level.php">MPOWER PLATINUM</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-parents">
      <div class="link">
        <span class="plus">+</span>
        <span class="minus">-</span>
        <a href="#">OUR SEGMENTS</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in css itself as the div will be the `last-child` or `only-child` if it doesn't have a submenu. so you can achieve it by using

```
.nav-parents > div.link:last-child > span{
  display:none;
}
```

```css
.nav-parents > div.link:last-child > span{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="multitoggle">
                <ul id="accordions">
                    <li class="nav-parents">
                        <div class="link"> <span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span> <a href="#">CURRENT ACCOUNTS</a></div>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="../current/third-level.php">MPOWER CLASSIC</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../current/third-level.php">MPOWER GOLD</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../current/third-level.php">MPOWER PLATINUM</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-parents">
                        <div class="link"> <span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span> <a href="#">OUR SEGMENTS</a></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**Jquery way:-**

If you still want to do it on jquery you can remove easily by

```
$(window ).load(function(e) {
        $('.nav-parents > div.link:only-child > span').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```js
$(window ).load(function(e) {
        $('.nav-parents > div.link:last-child > span').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multitoggle">
                <ul id="accordions">
                    <li class="nav-parents">
                        <div class="link"> <span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span> <a href="#">CURRENT ACCOUNTS</a></div>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="../current/third-level.php">MPOWER CLASSIC</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../current/third-level.php">MPOWER GOLD</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../current/third-level.php">MPOWER PLATINUM</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-parents">
                        <div class="link"> <span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span> <a href="#">OUR SEGMENTS</a></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: i think this is just an example, he might have menus that have no submenu and not last.